# Proof that there exists at most one function $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $\phi'(x)=-\phi(x)$ and $\phi(0)=1$

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that there exists at most one function $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $\phi'(x)=-\phi(x)\;\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\phi(0)=1$.

**My work so far:** I tried a proof by contradiction but haven't been able to come close to a solution in a formal manner, however intuitively I would say that since we have that if there exist $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\neq\psi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with the above properties, since $\phi(0)=\psi(0)$ and $\phi'(x)=-\phi(x)\land\psi'(x)=-\psi(x)\;\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, we should get that their derivatives get arbitrarily close to each other and thus might be able to conclude that $\psi=\phi$ but I haven't been able to do this in a formal manner.

Thank you very much in advance.

---

**Solution:** From @LordSharkTheUnkown's comment we can see that $(e^x(\phi(x)-\psi(x))')=0\;\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ and since $e^x$ can never be zero, we get that $\phi(x)=\psi(x)\;\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Differentiate $e^x(\phi(x)-\psi(x))$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you, I have edited the question.

Comment: @user you should actually answer your own question as opposed to putting the solution in the question (I think)

Comment: Add the solution as an answer, not in the question

Comment: An old manoevre: If $\phi'(x)=f(x)\phi(x)$ where $f$ is continuous, take $g$ with $g'=-f.$ Then $(\phi(x)e^{g(x)})'=0$ so $\phi(x)=ke^{-g(x)}$ for some constant $k,$ as stated in Chapter 1 of countless  textbooks on Differential Equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some methods that do not involve using the exponential function

**Method 1:** Use Cauchy-Lipschitz condition (this would show that a solution exist locally and it is unique).

**Method 2:** Assume that there are two solutions $\phi,\psi$, define $f=\frac{\phi}{\psi}$ then $f'(x)=0$ which means that $f(x)=f(0)=1$.

Note: there is a small issue here, you have to prove that $\psi(x)\ne 0$, one way to do that is to show that $\frac{d}{dx}\psi(x)\psi(-x)=0$. Therefore $\psi(x)\psi(-x)=1$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

**Method 3:** Prove that for any rational number $x$, $\phi(x)>0$ and $\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$ for any rational numbers $x,y$. Therefore, $\phi(x)=\phi(1)^x$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ and by continuity $\phi(x)=\phi(1)^x$ (Although, I would be careful with real exponents).  This means that there is a unique $\phi$.

**Why these three methods:** These are by no means the only methods to show that there is at most one solution. Usually, students are introduced to the exponential function without any explanation of where $e$ comes from, if you follow the third method you would see that the solution to the differential equation is of the form $c^x$, the only remaining question is "what is $c$?". A more elaborate analysis would show that it is none other than the lovely number $e\approx 2.71$.

Comment: Out of all these, my preferred approach is method 2. +1 here

Answer (score 1):

$\phi'(x)=-\phi(x)$ implies $\frac{d\phi}{\phi}=-\,dx$ which gives $\phi(x)=Ce^{-x}$.

Now $\phi(0)=1$ gives $C=1$. Hence $\phi(x)=e^{-x}$. Hence exactly one function !